# Elasticsearch Date parsing error in 7.x version

Tags: elasticsearch

Im using Elasticsearch 7.1 and i have defined the format in my index mappings as below :

```
 "ManufacturerDate": {
       "type": "date",
       "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'ZZ'|| yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'ZZ'||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"
        }
```

But im getting date parsing error when searching against the date - "2020-07-09T00:12:22.011-00:00". The format yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX is already defined as one of the accepted formats.
The error is

```
Failed to parse date field [2020-07-09T00:12:22.011-00:00] with format [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'ZZ'||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'ZZ'||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX]:
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Working example with mapping and search query.

**To know more about the Date data type refer to this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html).
The search query mentioned below is for finding exact date type values.**

**To Return documents that contain terms within a provided range refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html)**

**Mapping :**

```
    {
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ManufacturerDate": {
       "type": "date",
       "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'ZZ'||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
    {
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "ManufacturerDate": {
        "value": "2020-07-09T00:12:22.011-00:00"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "my_index",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1.0,
    "_source": {
      "ManufacturerDate": "2020-07-09T00:12:22.011-00:00"
    }
  }
]
```

**Update 1:**

You can even use [Constant score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html)

**Search query:**

```
 {
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "ManufacturerDate": "2020-07-09T00:12:22.011-00:00"
        }
      },
      "boost": 1.2
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "my_index",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1.2,
    "_source": {
      "ManufacturerDate": "2020-07-09T00:12:22.011-00:00"
    }
  }
]
```

**Update 2: By changing the order of patterns the query works (Using ES version 7.2)**

**Mapping:**

```
    {
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ManufacturerDate": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'ZZ'||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index data:**

```
    {
  "ManufacturerDate": "2020-07-09T00:12:22.011-00:00"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
 {
  "query": {
    "constant_score": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "ManufacturerDate": "2020-07-09T00:12:22.011-00:00"
        }
      },
      "boost": 1.2
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result :**

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_index": "my_index5",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "1",
    "_score": 1.2,
    "_source": {
      "ManufacturerDate": "2020-07-09T00:12:22.011-00:00"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply!! im using a constant score query with filter. will that change the way it returns?  "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [ {
                    "range": {
                      "ManufacturerDate": {
                        "from": "2020-07-09T00:12:22.011-00:00",  }}},
             ], } } }

Comment: @shdu12 you can use constant score query also, please go through my updated answer

Comment: @shdu12 did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you

Comment: seems like a perfect example. im trying to get it working and it gives me the same error. will update you shortly!! thank you so much.

Comment: Can you try with this:  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "ManufacturerDate": {
       "type": "date",
      "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'ZZ'||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"
    }
  }

Comment: @shdu12 I tried with above mapping also, and indexing the same data i.e. ```{
  "ManufacturerDate":"2020-07-09T00:12:22.011-00:00"
}``` , and running the same search query as mentioned above, it is perfectly giving the same search result as shown above (using both constant score query and term query)

Comment: @shdu12 can u please tell if u are getting any error in the search query result, as on my end it is working fine?

Comment: failed to parse date field [2020-07-09T00:12:22.011-00:00] with format [yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'ZZ'||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX]: [Text '2020-07-09T00:12:22.011-00:00' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23]

Comment: @shdu12 Are u using the same mapping and search query as I mentioned in the answer? And which version of ES are you using?

Comment: yes its same i copied and im using elasticsearch 7.1.

Comment: @shdu12 can u please go through my updated answer and try this query also along with updated mapping. I was working on ES version 7.8, and all the above queries which I have mentioned before in my answer works, but it was throwing some error for ES version 7.2. So please try with the updated answer (This is working for ES version 7.2)

Comment: thanks for the answer and the changing the order works. it used to work in previous releases. is there something changed in es 7.1? Any idea.

Comment: @shdu12 thank u for accepting the answer :) Can u please upvote this as well